# In Android how to detect which sim receive a ussd message or which sim slot receives a ussd message?

Tags: android, ussd, receiver, slot, dual-sim

I am building an android application where an user dialing an USSD code selecting any sim slot and then I read USSD message.

Here I know from which SIM this USSD message belong to SIM first or SIM second. As user only selects SIM slot from my application.

Issue: If user dial USSD code from out side of my application. Here I don't know user selection.

Is there any method from which I can get the information of SIM slot from which 
the user had dial USSD code.